# How can i get object using his handle in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I try to make a small image aquisition and procesing tool in Matlab.
My code:

```
himage=preview(source)
```

himage is a handle to image object, then i need to show image handles by himage. I have to try imshow function. 
I have handle to image object, i know how to access to object properties using his handle but how can i get object by his handle?

Answer (score 0):

If your `preview` function contains a call to `imshow` somewhere, you capture the handle like so:

```
himage = imshow(source)
```